# Criando Thread dinamicamente com Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Bom dia terráqueos,

Existe a possibilidade de fazer o spring-boot criar thread quando necessária e também matar a mesma ?

Comment: Qual seria o cenário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque a anotação `@EnableAsync` na sua `Application.java` e dê um `extends` na classe `AsyncConfigurerSupport`.
Com isso será possível criar um `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, segue exemplo abaixo.

```
 @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Segue link do guia do próprio Spring Boot:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/